# Windows CMD write into File with Escape Sequences

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I try to write into a `.txt` file the following way:

```
echo asdf >> file.txt
```

The problem is, when i have special characters, i get an error:

```
echo asdf & asdf >> file.txt
```

Obviously, this doesn't work (CMD tries to run asdf).
So i thought about escape Sequences and used this:

```
echo "asdf & asdf" >> file.txt
```

This works, but now my file actually contains `"asdf & asdf"` instead of `asdf & asdf`.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the ampersand.

```
echo asdf ^& echo asdf
```

In batch files `^` is used as escape char (the next character is a literal) and as line continuation character (if it is the last character in line, command line continues on next line)